# Sending information to a ngnix from php on the same server without http

Tags: php, nginx, connection, rabbitmq, real-time

We are developing a realtime app and we are using nginx push stream module for a websockets part. Firstly, data is send from a client to a php script that does some authentication and stores needed information in database and then pushes information to nginx that later sends it to a subscribed users on a specific sockets. Quite often there will be situations when there are more that 30 http requests made from this script to local nginx (*which I am not exactly sure is a bad thing?*).

**Question**
Is it possible to send information from php to nginx without http requests? Is there any way that my php script can communicate with nginx?  What is a best practise to handle this kind of communications? Is sending 30+ http requests per php script a good practise?

I have read towards some AMQP solutions but haven't found information where nginx is a consumer of messages from rabbitmq.

I will gladly provide any additional information if something is not clear.

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to do here, NGINX works on http protocol and you need some protocol to send the request from php script to nginx. Apart from that NGINX is a reverse proxy so you cant use it for RabbitMQ

Comment: @Pulkit Thanks for your comment. I need some balancing like solution for ngnix web socket module. Because as John Siu mentioned it seems like overkill to send 20+ http requests from php script to ngnix on my own server.

Comment: RusIanN: in case of loadbalancing have a look at this answer may be this can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29718992/2219920

Comment: Why doesn't the PHP simply send the information directly to the sockets?

Comment: If each in-bound request creates 30 out-bound requests you will run out of file descriptors on your server a lot quicker than you think during periods of high traffic.

Comment: @chugadie can you elaborate more on topic of file descriptors and how they will affect me? I have very basic knowledge of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I am assuming the following:**

**Current work flow:**

1. User run php script from command line, which communicate with a server side script/cgi setup in Nginx using http request
2. Server side script/cgi in Nginx will take the incoming data, process it and put it in database, or send out to end user

**OP concern:**

Efficiency of command line php script communicating with Nginx server side script using http protocol, which maybe overkill as the communication happen within the same server.

**Proposal 1**

1. Command line php script will write all information into file(s),
   then send one http request to Nginx server side cgi script
2. Nginx server cgi script, upon receiving the request, will pick up all
   information from file(s), then process it
3. ramfs (ram disk) can be use to minimize I/O to physical HD

**Proposal 2**

Combine your command line php script into the Nginx server side script, and create a web interface for it. Current command line user will login webpage to control the process they used to do it with command line tool.

**Pro:** No more inter-scripts/inter-process communication. The whole work flow is in one process. This maybe more scalable for the future also, as multiple users can log in through web interface and handle the process remotely. Additionally, they do not require OS level accounts.

**Con:** May need more development time. (But you only have to maintain one code base instead of two.)

Comment: Thanks for idea, but reading from file(s) seems like really slow for chat like app

Comment: @RuslanN If it is a chatting apps, maybe you can consider using unix socket instead of file

Comment: I am using websocket module for nginx. The problem is as you mentioned overkill as the communication happens with the same server. This happens because I need to do some processing on server side before sending data to receivers so overkill happens.

Comment: @RuslanN I have been thinking about your question and come up with one more proposal.

Comment: I am happy to hear it

Comment: So what you are telling is to put all work done in php (db communication, parsing json result) to a nginx side? I thought about this idea, but amount of work done in php script is quite big and this will slow workflow.
My current workflow: client (ios based or android) sends message using http request to api written in php. Php processes message, stores it does some additional work with it (authentication, notification and statistic related stuff) and then makes http request to nginx with parsed-json message which then is retrieved by client.

Comment: Base on your comment so far, seems your current flow from is as follow (1) Mobile client request is sent to php script over tcp (2) Standalone php script will authenticate, process data, update db, etc (3) Standalone php script communicate with nginx, (4) Naginx script send information to mobile client through websocket connection.

Comment: @RuslanN If my above assumption is true, then in the current flow, on top of a active websocket connection between mobile client and nginx, each time mobile client send a request, there is a additional tcp connection to the standalone php script, which is expensive and excessive.

Comment: If there is a active websocket connection, that means the mobile client already authenticate. Client request should definitely use the websocket connection to send request, this remove the authentication requirement for each request. This also remove the TCP connection setup and tear down for each request, which is expensive in terms of network communication.

Comment: Regarding db connection, you chould research database connection pool.

Comment: So to sum up what you are suggesting: transfer all message managing (parsing, validation and storing to database) to nginx side?

Comment: @RuslanN That is correct. It should one web application on the Nginx side.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you consider using [socket.io](http://socket.io/) and Amazon SNS?

In our infrastructure when we want to send a notification to a specific client subscribed on a socket.io channel, we send a payload to an Amazon SNS topic. This payload has "channel" attribute and the "message" to send to the client. I give just a snippet from our code that's easy to understand

```
$msg = array(
                'channel' => $receiver->getCometChannel(), //Channel id of the client to send the message 
                'data' => json_encode($payload) //The message to send to the client
    );
$client = $this->getSNSObject();
$client->publish(array(
            'TopicArn' => $topicArn,
            'Message' => json_encode($msg)
        ));
```

We have a node.js script that creates and endpoint on the port 8002 (http://your_ip:8002/receive) When Amazon SNS receives a payload from PHP backends, it forwards this payload to this endpoint and then the only thing to do is processing the payload and send the message to the corresponding client via socket.js. Here goes the node.js script:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    pfx:fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certificate.pfx') //optional, for SSL support for socket.js
};


var io = require('socket.io')(8001);


// open the socket connection
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('subscribe', function(data) { socket.join(data.channel); });
        socket.on('unsubscribe', function(data) { socket.leave(data.channel); });
        socket.on('message', function (data) {
                io.sockets.in(data.channel).emit('message', data.message);
        });
})

var http=require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if(req.method === 'POST' && req.url === '/receive') {
        return client(req, res);
    }
    res.writeHead(404);
    res.end('Not found.');
}).listen(8002);

var SNSClient = require('aws-snsclient');
var client = SNSClient(function(err, message) {
        try{
                var body=JSON.parse(message.Message)
                var channel=body.channel,data=(body.data);
                console.log(channel);
                io.sockets.in(channel).emit('message', {channel: channel, data: data});
        } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
        }
});
```

Maybe it seems complicated but i the idea is clear.

Comment: Thanks you for bringing AmazonSNS up. We are using similar model but instead of socket.io we are using ngnix_stream_push_module and we needed something to balance load and AmazonSNS seems like great solution so far. What do you think about sending from PHP backends to Amazon SNS which forwards to ngnix websocket module? And what speed does this Amazov service provide?  Is it good for real time chats?

Comment: Also, is it possible to send messages to amazon sns in batch?

Comment: Here you can nginx_stream_push_module instead of socket.io. I tried both solutions and socket.io is far better because it also has its client api etc. As you see the implementation is pretty short. For realtime chat, there's some delay in SNS. It can be used but you should implement and test before. There's no batch api for SNS but for SQS yes.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer step by step:

1. Is sending 30+ http requests per php script a good practise?

It's not a problem until you satisfied with the speed. You have possible two potential problems with that solution:

```
a. high timing to reestablish http connection each request; 
b. when concurrent requests reach its maximum nginx can skip some of your requests;
```

2. What is a best practise to handle this kind of communications?

As you said, best practice to use Query interface. But I am not sure, is there a way to handle it on nginx side (I am not clear with technology you using on nginx side).

Also you can use long polling connection to send requests to nginx, that will decrease latency from problem (a), but it can issue some new problems.

Comment: I am using websockets from nginx push_stream module if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What about using PHP-FPM connected to Nginx over Unix domain sockets using the FastCGI protocol? That's the fastest way to do IPC between Nginx and PHP — there's very little IO overhead, compared to an Internet socket.

Comment: By doing this php script will send data to nginx inside server? Can you provide some sources where I can learn more about this

Comment: Both the Nginx and the PHP processes have to run on the same machine. Google for PHP-FPM and Nginx, and you'll see lots of tutorials.

Comment: See for instance [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-debian-7). The Unix socket in Nginx configuration file looks like `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;`

Comment: Can you tell what solution you've chosen? Just curious.

Comment: We have chosen to optimize current workflow and while we are going to monitor load on a current system we will try two ideas for out sockets: nodejs one and ratchet based with queue system for load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that we tried before was deploying an ejabberd server (you can customize it) write a small javascript client using strophe client. http://blog.wolfspelz.de/2010/09/website-chat-made-easy-with-xmpp-and.html?m=1 good blog post about the topic. If you want to develop a chat application i would go for this option.

Another advantage, your users can also use xmpp clients to connect to your chat platform.