# How does an application written for websocket server work with a web application on Apache server

Tags: websocket

I have read articles about websocket for web application for a while. I found most people mention starting a independent websocket server (or daemon), some implementation are listed in http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html, e.g. Ratchet, Wrench

Well-know servers for PHP like Apache, Nginx don't have built-in support for websocket. They all use a proxy module for a independent websocket server.

If I write an application for websocket server, how can this application communication or access the web applicaiton I deploy on a web server like Apache? For example, access the class of my web application, connect database...

Is there a server in PHP world like Tomcat that supports HTTP and websocket at the same time?

(added)
What I want to achieve is my javascript program can communicate with my web application on Apache via websocket.

Javascript on a page <--- websocket ---> web application on apache

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584618/sending-information-to-a-ngnix-from-php-on-the-same-server-without-http/29731342#29731342 maybe this answer helps.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. But I don't understand what's the relation between your answer and websocket. Socket.io client connects to a node.js http server, how does it fit my requirement?

Comment: Socket.io uses websocket as transport method. From your php backend you can send a json payload to node.js and node.js can push this payload to client side

Comment: So you mean the websocket connection looks like: 
`PHP backend <--> websocket server <--> browser `

Both a browser and PHP establish a websocket connection to an independent websocket server, and the websocket server forward messages between 2 ends. right?